# In python, is it considered better to define a module with functions or a module with a class that contains functions?

Tags: python

In my code either of the above two options would work equally well but I am interested in finding out the pros and cons of both approaches.

Comment: Define a class if you plan to create instances of it - IMO it's poor style to use a class if you only want a namespace (which the module already provides)

Comment: A class has a purpose, it's not a place to put random functions. If a module works use a module.

Comment: Oh, and this is probably a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the functions are completely stateless, a module with functions would work just fine and is simpler.

If, one the other hand, there is state involved, it is usually better to encapsulate that state in a class, and provide the functionality through member functions.

Comment: In Python, modules, like most other things, _are_ objects and have a class and can have a state.

Comment: That doesn't make them a good representation of things that will have multiple instances.

Comment: @martineau, modules are objects but they are *singleton* objects. Having them hold any kind of state is pointless unless that state must be shared.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, I know they're singletons. However I don't think having them have a state is always pointless.

Comment: In particular they can hold state that is constant, sometimes also configuration values or cached values. Also, let's not forget that good'ol modular programming does have a place still. Forcing everything and the kitchensink into a class sometimes just adds overhead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, every thing in python is an object, so, there is no considerable difference in terms of performance of using functions over classes or vice versa.

If you are a beginner, then I would recommend using module with functions, as it's easier and more straight forward.

The down side of this technique is that you might have a lot of functions in the same module, which make it harder mentally to track and remember what functions in which modules

If you are comfortable with using classes, which will provide the power of encapsulation (data/attributes + methods/logic), and put all the logically related stuff in one container, the class, then you can start from here.

You can customize how you want your class to interact in your code, by adding: Meta-classes, descriptors, and all python special functions, which can override default behaviors of each part in your class.

Using classes, will help you to better logically-represent real world problems, e.g. you can say I have a machine class, describe all of its properties/specifications with data/attributes and define how it acts, takes input, and produces output with methods. And same thing can happen when you write a new protocol or a standard, it's easier to represent its components/input/output/behaviors with classes that can describe each of these with logical entities/containers.

Also classes are better for team-working, you are not going to write everything on your own, there must be a blueprint for your project, and this blueprint should be translated to smaller blocks, inputs, and outputs; classes are the best to be used in this situation.

Comment: The unprofessional Python standard library has plenty of bare functions in modules.

Comment: Yep, agreed. Actually python has lots of things to do to meet the increased demand. Very fast paced community-creating-modules, and very slow python core development (talking mainly about CPython).

Comment: I was being sarcastic in calling the Python standard library unproffessional.  Python is not Java.  We don't need to shove everything into classes.

Comment: Writing things in modules doesn't make them more professional, nor more more organized. Working on really big projects with only modules will make things like a mess,and not to forget code statelessness;classes should exist to make things more tidy and more encapsulated. If using modules is the best way to go, then main-stream frameworks like Django, Twisted and many others wouldn't have used classes all over the place, for reasons I listed in my answer. The strongest reason for those who prefer to use functions in modules is simplicity, I don't think there is an added benefit over classes.